# How do I export org-anniversary dates to iCalender?

Tags: org-export, diary

I have an org-file with entries of the form

```
* Abel's birthday party
  <2023-11-13>
```

and with entries of the form

```
* Abel Jacobi
%%(org-anniversary 1978 11 11) Abel %d
```

When I export to `ics` (e.g. `org-export-dispatch` > `[c]` Export to icalendar > `[f]` Current file), only the former type of entries is included in the resulting `ics`-file.  How can I also include the latter entries?

(Both types of events show up in my agenda view in emacs.)

Comment: One of the two should be "the former": they cannot both be the "the latter". Please fix.

Comment: Does it work if you use `diary-anniversary` instead?  (Important -- use the correct argument order for your value of `calendar-date-style`).  I can see `icalendar--convert-to-ical` attempting to handle that, but maybe the export code just doesn't know about `org-anniversary` (which would seem weird, granted; but worth testing).  If it's that, please report it as a bug.

Comment: Yes!  If I use `diary-anniversary` then the event gets exported correcty to icalendar.  But it no longer shows up in my agenda view in emacs, and `%d` gets exported verbatim rather than converted to the appopriate integer.  Where exactly should I file a bug report?

Comment: This looks org-mode specific (I suspect it should be supported by `ox-icalendar.el`), so refer to https://orgmode.org/manual/Feedback.html and https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html#org0ba954b (and it would be worth checking whether there are other org-specific diary-style forms lacking support which can be addressed at the same time).

Comment: n.b. `C-h v org-agenda-include-diary` *might* solve the "no longer shows up in my agenda view" part.  I think by default that's only going to pull things from `diary-file`, but see also the notes on `#include` syntax in `C-h f diary-include-files` and `C-h i g (emacs)Importing Diary` and `C-h i g (emacs)Fancy Diary Display`.  (Hopefully including the org file wouldn't make that a recursive loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the behaviour I reported was a bug/missing feature in Org version 9.5.5.  This is fixed in Org 9.6.